# How to query opportunities that have a Close Date in the past, but are within an account that has an opportunity with Close Date after Today?

Tags: soql, query, object

How to query opportunities that have a closedate in the past, but are within an account that has a closedate after Today?

Below is the query I'm trying to execute, but I get the following error:

```
select id 
from opportunity 
where closedate <= Today 
and accountid not in 
    (select accountid from opportunity where closedate >= Today)
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: what's the error you are getting when you run the query ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's achievable by doing an inner select referencing another sObject (Account via AccountId). I would query the accounts first and put their IDs in a set that I can then use in the other query:

```
Set <Id> accountIds = new Set <Id> ();

for (Opportunity oppty : [select accountid from opportunity where closedate >= Today])
{
    accountIds.add(oppty.AccountId);
}

system.debug([select id from opportunity where closedate <= Today and accountid not in :accountIds]);
```